# How to add a custom made Java program to the IBM Tivoli Provisioning Manager ( TPM ) as a Java Plugin?

Tags: java, plugins, provisioning, tivoli

I need to add my custom made java program to the IBM Tivoli Provisioning manager as a Java Plugin. Please help with detailed procedures.

Answer (score 1):

by plugin do you mean a complete new area in the maximo interface or are you trying to add a java call to have a provisioning workflow call? If you haven't installed the Application Developer Environment I'd recommend installing that. Once you have written your java plugin compile it into a .tcdriver automation package and install it using (as tioadmin) $TIO_HOME/tools/tc-driver-installer.sh install    note the package name should not have .tcdriver in it and should be located in $TIO_HOME/drivers and owned by tioadmin:tioadmin.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v45r1/topic/com.ibm.tivoli.tpm.wkf.doc/workflows/twkf_gettingstarted.html?resultof=%22%41%50%44%45%22%20%22%61%70%64%22%20